# Selenium webdriver highlight element before clicking

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-testing

I'm working on a set of selenium UI tests that are written in Python. On a previous project I was using WatiN and C#.

The WatiN framework had a feature you could enable that would 'highlight' the element you were clicking, selecting or typing into. The element would get a yellow border around it while the action was performed. I found this extremely helpful while troubleshooting broken tests, I could often see from the test run if the wrong element was being clicked.

I was wondering if Selenium webdriver has a similar feature that I can turn on. Basically I would like some sort of visual indication of what element is being interacted with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium RC could do this but there is no direct API method to do this in WebDriver. Your options are:

1) Use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` implementation in your language bindings to access the `Highlight` method.

2) Simply call some javascript using the `JavascriptExecutor` (or similar implementation in your language bindings) to do the job for you. This will mimic what **Selenium RC/option 1** would achieve.

The Javascript to call exists here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js

The function to note is the `highlight` function. Just load this script using the JavascriptExecutor (search to find out how to do this in your programming language).

You can then compare this to see how the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` implementation in the Java API's are using it:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/internal/seleniumemulation/Highlight.java

Use this, to do this same in your own code.

As a side note, the Selenium IDE for Firefox can highlight methods as well.

Comment: Above link is resulting in 404. Could you please help me to get working url for the same?