# How can I highlight element on a webpage using Selenium-Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I have been handed over a existing selenium framework which uses python for scripting. For debugging(& other) purposes, I would like to highlight the element on which action is being taken currently (input box, link, drop-down etc.)

Though I could find solutions to define a function and calling the function wherever I need to highlight the element(as examples given below), what I need is a solution at the framework level.

1. [Selenium webdriver highlight element before clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791866/selenium-webdriver-highlight-element-before-clicking)
2. https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/intermediate-topics/playing-with-javascript-and-javascript-executor/highlighting-a-web-element-on-webpage/

Is it possible to implement any solution at the framework / script level in Python (or any other language which can be integrated with python scripts), so that I don't have to call the functions explicitly.

P.S. I am just beginning to use Python, so excuse me if its a simple/straight forward. Will appreciate if someone can point me to any existing solution or can provide their own solution.

Comment: I don't understand the need to highlight the element for debugging. logs should be enough to understand what when wrong. Also the solution which has provided by santosh will slow down your execution. (.3x number of elements)

Comment: I understand but as I said I am new to Python (done very little programming so far) so highlighting of element makes it easier for me to debug the failure points. I agree, I'll get comfortable with debugging using logs after a few months but for now I can only appreciate any solution to my problem.

Comment: There is no easy solution for this. either you write wrapper for each and every action for which you want to highlight the element, or before you do any action call this method in your tests manually. either way it's costly, it would be costly when you will have to disable that as well.

Comment: Thanks @GaurangShah

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this code, but this should work.

```
import time

def highlight(element):
 """Highlights (blinks) a Selenium Webdriver element"""
  driver = element._parent
  def apply_style(s):
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",element, s)
  original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
  apply_style("background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
  time.sleep(.3)
  apply_style(original_style)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Source - https://gist.github.com/dariodiaz/3104601

Comment: as far as I understand this function still needs to be called for every element and won't be implemented at class / framework level. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: write this as separate py file and import this your actual class file. Use it whenever required.. Did you need to highlight the element for each and every element by default?

Comment: yes.. that's what i want to do. Highlight every web element acted upon when the automation script is executed.

Comment: In that case, we can create a wrapper def and proceed with. Lets say if we need to click on an element, pass the element to another method, which first highlights the element and then executes the actual selenium click. For each and every action a separate def.