# Python Selenium - highlight element doesn't do anything

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, highlight

I'm trying to highlight elements on the following webpage using python selenium. I'm using the solution posted here: [How can I highlight element on a webpage using Selenium-Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440255/how-can-i-highlight-element-on-a-webpage-using-selenium-python) but it doesn't produce any effect at all. I don't get any error message, it simply doesn't highlight the element I've selected.
Has anybody faced the same problem?
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice"
driver.get(url)

def highlight(element):
    """Highlights (blinks) a Selenium Webdriver element"""
    driver = element._parent
    def apply_style(s):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                              element, s)
    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("border: 2px solid red;")
    time.sleep(.3)
    apply_style(original_style)


open_window_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("openwindow")
highlight(open_window_elem)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Works fine for me. Note that it highlights element (add *2 pixels red* border) for *0.3* seconds only, so you might just miss that effect

You can add more parameters to function, like TimeToHighlight, Color, BorderSize:

```
def highlight(element, effect_time, color, border):
    """Highlights (blinks) a Selenium Webdriver element"""
    driver = element._parent
    def apply_style(s):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                              element, s)
    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("border: {0}px solid {1};".format(border, color))
    time.sleep(effect_time)
    apply_style(original_style)
```

and then call as

```
open_window_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("openwindow")
highlight(open_window_elem, 3, "blue", 5)
```

This will add *blue 5 pixels* border to element for *3* seconds

Comment: you're totally right! Thank you very much Andersson, much appreciated your help