# Select/Highlight/Mark partial text in p-Tag with WebDriver

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

I have this markup:

```
<body>
  <p>
    Test 1<br/>
    Test 2
  </p>
</body>
```

Now I want to select "Test 1" to be able to apply certain styles with a WYSIWIG editor on it. Is there a possibility to select this part of the text? If not: How would I select the text of a `<p></p>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium - highlight element doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207164/python-selenium-highlight-element-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: My description with applying a bold style to it was misleading, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript` this is achievable (elem is IWebElement that contains text, value is the part of the text that should be selected/highlighted):

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript("var elem = arguments[0];" +
                         "var searchText = arguments[1];" +
                         "var selection = window.getSelection();" +
                         "var range = document.createRange();" +
                         "if (elem.innerText === searchText) {" +
                           "range.selectNode(elem);" +
                         "}" +
                         "else {" +
                           "var textNode;" +
                           "for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) { var node = elem.childNodes[i]; if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.nodeValue.indexOf(searchText) >= 0) { textNode = node; } }" +
                           "var startIndex = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(searchText);" +
                           "var endIndex = startIndex + searchText.length;" +
                           "range.setStart(textNode, startIndex);" +
                           "range.setEnd(textNode, endIndex);" +
                         "}" +
                         "selection.removeAllRanges();" +
                         "selection.addRange(range);", elem, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling need to be applied to an element, not a text node.  With this in mind you aren't going to be able to easily apply a change to just the `Test 1` text.

To make things easier you could ask the developer to wrap some `<span>` tags around the text you want to highlight, this will then make it an element level change.

I'm sure there is some horrific JavaScript hack to turn the text into an element and style it, but I would really suggest you do not go down that route.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js script solution that will bold the text node.

First let me show show how to do it in js (used chrome devtools console here for understanding). Then we can port this to selenium

```
// get the text node that you want to bold
var textNode = $x('//p/text()[1]')[0];
// create a bold element
var boldEle = document.createElement('b');
// copy the text from text node to boldEle
boldEle.innerText = textNode.nodeValue;
// place the boldEle before the current text which you want to bold
textNode.parentElement.insertBefore(boldEle,textNode.parentElement.childNodes[0]);
// remove the original textNode
textNode.remove();
```

**Screenshot:** chrome console.
 [image]

Now convert this to a function and get it worked from selenium.

**Python:**

```
jsFunction = """window.boldTextNode =function(parentXpath,textPosition){
                // get the text node that you want to bold
                var parent = arguments[0];
                var textPosition = arguments[1];
                var txtPosition = 0;
                var child = parent.firstChild;debugger;
                while(child) {
                  if (child.nodeType === 3){                        
                    if (txtPosition===(textPosition-1)){
                      var textNode = child;                
                      break;
                    }}else{txtPosition+=1;}
                  child = child.nextSibling;
                }
                // create a bold element
                var boldEle = document.createElement('b');
                // copy the text from text node to boldEle
                boldEle.innerText = textNode.nodeValue;
                // place the boldEle before the current text which you want to bold
                textNode.parentElement.insertBefore(boldEle,textNode.parentElement.childNodes[0]);
                // remove the original textNode
                textNode.remove();}
            """
# load the function so that you can call where ever you want
driver.execute_script(jsFunction)

# get the parent element
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p")
# now bold the text using the js function
driver.execute_script("boldTextNode(arguments[0],arguments[1]);",ele,1)
```

Comment: Sorry my question was misleading, I want to select the chars to apply some styles with a WYSIWYG editor :(